# How to make sure a team wins more often than it loses in a tournament with n matches having equal probabilities of wins, losses and draws each?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> In a tournament, team X plays with each of six other teams once. For each match the probabilities of a win, a draw and a loss are equal. Find the probability that team X finishes with more wins than losses.

I don't know if I can call it exactly a binomial probability problem but here's how I approached it:

We know that probability of win, loss or draw is $\frac{1}{3}$ each.

Let's make some cases:

CASE 1: When number of draws is 0: It would be 6, 5 or 4 wins.

$(\frac{1}{3})^6(\binom{6}{6}+ \binom{6}{5} + \binom{6}{4})$

CASE 2: When there is 1 draw. It would be 5, 4 or 3 wins.

$(\frac{1}{3})^6(\frac{6!}{5!}+\frac{6!}{4!}+\frac{6!}{3!2!})$

CASE 3: 2 Draws, thus 4 or 3 wins

$(\frac{1}{3})^6(\frac{6!}{4!2!}+\frac{6!}{3!2})$

CASE 4: 3 draws, thus 3 or 2 wins

$(\frac{1}{3})^6(\frac{6!}{3!3!}+\frac{6!}{3!2!})$

CASE 5: 4 draws, thus 2 wins

$(\frac{1}{3})^6(\frac{6!}{2!4!})$

CASE 6: 5 draws, thus 1 win

$(\frac{1}{3})^6(\frac{6!}{5!})$

Adding them all up gives the result: $\frac{284}{729}$.

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: The correct answer is $\frac{98}{243}$.

Comment: Is the correct answer $\frac{294}{729}$ by the way? Just want to make sure.

Comment: @GarethMa Nah, the correct answer is $\frac{98}{243}$. I'll add this in the edit.

Comment: $\frac{294}{3} = 98$.

Comment: @GarethMa I am sorry, I thought you were just asking about my result $\frac{284}{729}$. Yeah, that's the answer

Comment: @BrianTung the OP's result does not reduce, but Gareth's does

Comment: @BrianTung The sum I am getting is not 294 though.

Comment: @D S is correct

Comment: @DS: Oops, just misread, yes. I saw the expressions were right and didn't notice the difference between $284$ and $294$. I expect the OP just made a minor mistake in the arithmetic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't show any of your working, but (tldr) **the formulas that you have written down are all correct**. In particular, for cases $1$ to $6$ you should get $\frac{1}{729}\left(22, 96, 75, 80, 15, 6\right)$ respectively, and summing them gives $\frac{294}{729} = \frac{98}{243}$ as you stated.

I would also like to share an easier method. Note that

$$
\mathrm{Prob}\left(\# \text{Wins} > \# \text{Loses}\right) = \mathrm{Prob}\left(\# \text{Wins} < \# \text{Loses}\right)
$$

This is due to symmetry. We also know another formula,

$$
\mathrm{Prob}\left(\# \text{Wins} > \# \text{Loses}\right) + \mathrm{Prob}\left(\# \text{Wins} = \# \text{Loses}\right) + \mathrm{Prob}\left(\# \text{Wins} < \# \text{Loses}\right) = 1
$$

Therefore, if we can find $\mathrm{Prob}\left(\# \text{Wins} = \# \text{Loses}\right)$ then we can compute the desired probability easily. This should be easier to compute since it's just $\sum_{i = 0}^3 \mathrm{Prob}\left(\# \text{Wins} = \# \text{Loses} = i\right) = \sum_{i = 0}^3 \frac{1}{3^6}\binom{6}{2i}\binom{2i}{i} = \frac{141}{729}$. The rest follows since $\frac{98}{243} = \frac{1}{2}\left(1 - \frac{141}{729}\right)$. I summed over $\binom{6}{2i}\binom{2i}{i}$ as it is the number of ways to choose the non-draws, then choose the games where the team wins. Note that you can interpret this as assigning each game either Win, Draw or Lose to the $6$ games, so it equals to the multinomial coefficient $\binom{6}{i, i, 6 - 2i} \equiv \binom{6}{2i}\binom{2i}{i} = \frac{6!}{(2i)!(6-2i)!}\frac{(2i!)}{i!i!} = \frac{6!}{i!i!(6-2i)!}$.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork (I removed my previous comment) A better explanation is that under the symmetry, you're overcounting the case if the number of wins equals the number of losses. Say the two teams play $3$ games. The cases that fits the description would be (Wins, Loses) = $(1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1)$, and applying the symmetry gives $(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)$. But it's missing the cases $(0, 0)$, $(1, 1)$ and $(2, 2)$. These are the fixed points of $\sigma : \mathbb{Z}^2 \to \mathbb{Z}^2, \sigma((x, y)) = (y, x)$.

Answer (score 2):

This is correct.

A somewhat faster way to do this is first to compute the probability that there are as many wins as losses. The number of ways this can happen is

- 0 wins, 0 losses: 1
- 1 win, 1 loss, 4 draws: $\binom64 \cdot 2 = 30$
- 2 wins, 2 losses, 2 draws: $\binom62 \cdot \binom42 = 90$
- 3 wins, 3 losses: $\binom63 = 20$

Therefore the probability of the same number of losses and wins is $p_0 = \frac{1 + 30 + 90 + 20}{3^6} = \frac{141}{729}$

Since wins and losses are equally likely, the desired probability is $(1 - p_0)/2 = \frac{98}{243}$.